# Random login failed error on Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have integrated a small console application to get the documents attached in a completed envelope and upload them to Sharepoint Document library.

On running the console application , I get the below error on the Login method

```
AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
loginInfo = authApi.Login();)
```

randomly. I understand this could be a issue with Rate limiting on Docusign Demo Environment.

I wanted to know if there is a way out of this to resolve the issue. I using the Docusign Nuget package to use the API's

```
        <HTML><HEAD>
        <TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
        <FONT face="Helvetica">
        <big><strong></strong></big><BR>
        </FONT>
        <blockquote>
        <TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
        <TR><TD>
        <FONT face="Helvetica">
        <big>Access Denied (authentication_failed)</big>
        <BR>
        <BR>
        </FONT>
        </TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>
        <FONT face="Helvetica">
        Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.
    </FONT>
    </TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>
    <FONT face="Helvetica">
    This is typically caused by an incorrect username and/or password, but could also be caused by network problems.
    </FONT>
    </TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>
    <FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
    <BR>
    For assistance, contact your network support team.
    </FONT>
    </TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
    </blockquote>
    </FONT>
```

Comment: Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45740463/3530898 it has code to call Auth code. Kindly let us know if you are using the same flow.

Comment: Yes I am using the same code for Login as is available on the SDK and corerecipes.cs, I have rechecked the question posted above and the error is not same. In my case I am getting the html response. I am now checking with my corp firewall team

Comment: Whats the endpoint you are using for authentication?

Comment: Although I am using the official SDK which has the class for Authentication . I used fiddler to get the aut/login endpoint request - https://demo.docusign.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you've posted here `"Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified."` is not an error message from the DocuSign platform.

I would verify where that error is coming from as it could be client side.  If you can't track it down I would start looking at the raw API request your code is sending and verifying the authentication info is going into the request as you expect.  You can use a tool like Fiddler to capture and inspect your outgoing requests.

Comment: No I have rechecked the issue is on this line
 AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
               
                loginInfo = authApi.Login();

Comment: Apologies  , Yes it looks like the error is thrown from the Proxy/gateway. Time to get hold of IT guys. Thanks @ergin

Comment: Yeah I suspected something of that nature, ok thanks for confirming.